# Serilog with Graylog not logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog, graylog

I have a Web API and I'm trying to log messages into Graylog, using Serilog. Now matter what I do, no messages are shown in my Graylog application. This is what I have so far:

This is in my Program.cs

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().
    ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration).
    Enrich.FromLogContext().
    CreateLogger();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

This is my configuration:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Graylog" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Graylog",
        "Args": {
          "hostnameOrAddress": "127.0.0.1",
          "port": "12201",
          "transportType": "Udp"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Centralized logging application"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And I'm trying to log a:

```
_logger.LogError(0, new Exception("Exception Message"), "Message", new WeatherForecast());
```

Can someone please help me? I need to see my exception inside Graylog.

Thanx a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is correct. Now you need to configure the Graylog side as the colleague above asked. To do this, go to the Graylog interface, more specifically at: System/Inputs -> Inputs. Then, create a GELF UDP entry with the respective port of your Graylog.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the input set up on the Graylog side? Have you verified that you can get messages to that input?

Finally, I noticed you were sending it to local host. Are both applications on the same machine? If not, you will want to put in the address of the Graylog server.

Comment: Yes both my App and the Graylog server run in my localhost. As far as the "input" is concerned, I don't know what you mean. What input?